# VPN service failed to start

Tags: ubuntu

I  want to use VPN L2TP connection.I have set up VPN service via

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:seriy-pr/network-manager-l2t
```

and configure new connection via L2TP type.
while connecting to service i am getting the following error  `**VPN  service failed to start.**`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/